# Apache Tomcat 8.0.15 not working with upgrade to JRE 1.8

Tags: java, tomcat8

I recently upgraded Java to JRE 1.8_202 from JRE 1.7 on our windows' servers:

1. On my production servers, I updated java virtual machine path at tomcatw.exe to jvm.dll of JRE 1.8_202 and restarted the service. and it started giving issues. Below is some error which I got.
2. On QA servers, when we on doing the same steps this worked completely fine.

### Could you please suggest?

When we revert this prod JVM parameter back to JRE7, this starts working again.

`13-Dec-2019 19:15:49.264 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-2] org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.checkThreadLocalMapForLeaks The web application [DocumentGen] created a ThreadLocal with key of type [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1] (value [org.apache.xmlbeans.impl.schema.SchemaTypeLoaderImpl$1@160adc50]) and a value of type [java.util.ArrayList] (value [[java.lang.ref.SoftReference@2306137e]]) but failed to remove it when the web application was stopped. Threads are going to be renewed over time to try and avoid a probable memory leak.`

Comment: I don't see any error, that's a warning of a memory leak when you're stopping your app. Did you actually have an error?

Comment: Thanks for the details. This warning is all I have in logs, etc.